# Configuring footnote position and spacing

Tags: spacing, formatting, footnotes, citing

(A) How do I shift the footnote vertically down 1 mm or so? (B) I want to introduce some additional space in between one foot note and the next one, and between the first footnote and the line that separates it from the regular text.

`\vspace{1mm}` inside the `\footnote{}` command does not solve this.

Using XeTex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, graphicx, setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.9}
TEXT.\footnote{\vspace{1mm} my footnote is here.}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

(C) How do I prevent a long footnote from partly continuing in the next page? (D) I must also find a way to linebreak in footnotes without justifying the first line.

The `footmisc` package (with the 'hang' option) only makes the footnote symbol flush to the left. (E) I would actually like to put it a couple points away from the left margin. (F) And make the footnote number bold.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Done. I listed the packages I am using here, in case that matters, in the code example.

Comment: i don't think (C) is possible if the footnote is longer than the available space on the page (but you can try to `\enlargethispage` to give more room).  as for (D), try putting `\endgraf` where you want the break; this is a no-frills equivalent of `\par`.  you may also have to use `\noindent` if you want the next line to start at the left margin.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want your line break to function (that is, if Barbara Beeton hasn't answered your question already)?  I can't see why `\\` wouldn't work.

Comment: \endgraf \noindent worked like I wanted! Great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if I got completely what you want to achieve...

- To *"introduce some additional space in between one foot note and the next one, and between the first footnote and the line that separates it from the regular text"* you can add the following line to your preamble (change `5mm` to `1mm` or whatever you need):

  ```
  \addtolength{\footnotesep}{5mm} % change to 1mm
  ```
- To *"make the footnote number bold"* you can add the following line to your preamble:

  ```
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}
  ```
- To *"put it a couple points away from the left margin"* you can load the package `footmisc` with the option `flushmargin`:

  ```
  \usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
  ```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, graphicx, setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\addtolength{\footnotesep}{5mm} % change to 1mm

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textbf{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.9}
TEXT.\footnote{my first footnote is here.}

TEXT.\footnote{my second footnote is here.}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You perfectly answered (A), (B), (E), (F) :) Exactly what I was looking for. Do you also know how to do (C) and (D)?

Comment: What if you don't want to add space between the line and the footnote but between the line and the main text above it?

Comment: \addtolength{\footnotesep}{5mm} not only adds space above the first note but also in-between them.  How can I just add it before them?

Comment: What if we don't want to introduce additional space in between one foot note and the next one, but only between the first footnote and the line that separates it from the regular text? I mean, only before all footnotes.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I know to modify footnote settings. I think you could use this for some of your issues. Put the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter                                                                 
    \def\footnoterule{\kern-6\p@        % you can put other values to increase vertical space between rule and notes (just try out); difference between the values after "kern" is the width of the rule!
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 5.7\p@}  % the in value is the length of the footnoterule
\makeatother

\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pt}    % vertical space between rule and main text

\setlength{\footnotesep}{12pt}  % vertical space between footnotes

\let\origfootnote\footnote       % font size of footnotes; changes \footnotesize command only inside footnotes!
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
   \renewcommand\footnotesize\scriptsize     % here there is scriptsize in footnotes (example)       
   \origfootnote{#1}}
```

Comment: You answered (B) :) like I was looking for. Do you also know how to do (C) and (D)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. C is something I would be interested in, too.

Answer (score 4):

```
\footnote{Hi}
\footnote{\vphantom{\Huge ${A^{A}}^{A}$}far away {\tt footnote}}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: That was very creative! :) Not quite automated, like above answers, but I upvoted it because it can be useful in some circumstance I expect

Comment: @GuidoJorg Also, we can use the 'tabular environment' inside the footnote such that we can make many effects. However, $@karlkoeller$ solution is quite nice. In that way we do not have to worry anymore along the document. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For (C), you may set `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000` in the preamble. This will prevent all footnotes to be split. If you want this only for a particular note, just say `\samepage` at the beginning of the note: `\footnote{\samepage ...}`.