# How to get the vertical space in between the breaking footnotes ( it is continue from previous page) and the another new footnote?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I would like to have a small vertical space between the footnote continuing from a previous page and the footnote of the current page.

I know there is a command `\footnotesep` to separate the footnotes (as explained in [Configuring footnote position and spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141906/64454)). However, this solution introduce a vertical space between *every* footnote. Yet I would like a vertical space only between footnote from previous page, and footnotes from current page, as shown below:

```
------------------
a sample footnote continued form the previous page.

6. Next footnote coming immediately after the breaking footnote
7. Another footnote from current page, without vertical space before.
```

Is possible to get this style automatically?

Comment: As far as I can tell the duplicate candidate adresses this for all footnotes, not only those leaking out of their page.

Comment: I've rephrased the question, in order to make it distinct from duplicate. @venkatesan Ramachandiran: Tell me if it match your initial intention.

Comment: This is what I got to say

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put a label at the beginning and at the end of each footnote. At the beginning of a footnote, if the labels of the previous one are different, it means that it was split. If the current footnote starts on the page where the previous one ends, then insert a vertical skip.

```
\newcounter{footnotecount} % footnote counter
\newlength\splitfootnoteskip % skip added after a split footnote
% the following makes \splitfootnoteskip equal to \baselineskip inside footnotes
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\global\setlength\splitfootnoteskip{\baselineskip}
\endgroup
\makeatletter
% save the original definition of \@footnotetext
\let\kernel@footnotetext\@footnotetext
% and redefine it to insert labels
\renewcommand\@footnotetext[1]{%
  \check@splitfn
  \stepcounter{footnotecount}%
  \kernel@footnotetext{%
    \edef\next{\noexpand\label{fnstart\thefootnotecount}}\next
    \ignorespaces#1%
    \edef\next{\noexpand\label{fnend\thefootnotecount}}\next}}
% check whether the previous note was split
% if \c@footnotecount is 0, this is the first footnote.
% Otherwise, check whether both labels are defined and equal.
% If they are both defined but different, and the labels for the current
% footnote are defined, check whether the current footnote starts on the
% page where the previous one ends.
% If so, insert \vskip\splitfootnoteskip
\newcommand\check@splitfn{%
  \ifnum\c@footnotecount=\z@\else
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempa\csname r@fnend\the\c@footnotecount\endcsname
      \ifx\tempa\relax\else
        \expandafter\ifx\csname r@fnstart\the\c@footnotecount\endcsname\tempa\else
          \count@=\c@footnotecount
          \advance\count@ 1\relax
          \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempb\csname r@fnstart\the\count@\endcsname
          \ifx\tempb\relax\else
            \edef\tempa{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\tempa}%
            \edef\tempb{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\tempb}%
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
              \insert\footins{\vskip\splitfootnoteskip}%
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Tahnk you, it is working

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran. Actually, my solution did not work completely. When the previous footnote is split, I forgot to check whether the current one starts on the page where the previous one ends. I edited my answer.